# Is it possible to track down which expression caused an NPE?

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, stack-trace, bytecode

When I get an NPE, I'll get a stack trace with line number.
That's helpful, but if the line is very dense and/or contains nested expression, it's still impossible to figure out which reference was null.

Surely, this information must've been available somewhere.
Is there a way to figure this out? (If not java expression, then at least the bytecode instruction that caused NPE would be helpful as well)

Edit #1: I've seen a few comments suggesting breaking up the line, etc, which, no offence, is really non-constructive and irrelevant. If I could do that, I would have ! Let just say this modifying the source is out of the question.

Edit #2: apangin has posted an excellent answer below, which I accepted. But it's SOOO COOL that I had to include the output here for anyone who doesn't want to try it out themselves! ;)

So suppose I have this driver program TestNPE.java

```
 1  public class TestNPE {
 2      public static void main(String[] args) {
 3          int n = 0;
 4          String st = null;
 5  
 6          System.out.println("about to throw NPE");
 7          if (n >= 0 && st.isEmpty()){
 8              System.out.println("empty");
 9          }
10          else {
11              System.out.println("othereise");
12          }
13      }
14      
15  }
```

The bytecode looks like this (showing only the main() method and omitting other irrelevant parts)

```
Code:
  stack=2, locals=3, args_size=1
     0: iconst_0
     1: istore_1
     2: aconst_null
     3: astore_2
     4: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;                                              
     7: ldc           #3                  // String about to throw NPE                                                                     
     9: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V                                      
    12: iload_1
    13: iflt          34
    16: aload_2
    17: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/String.isEmpty:()Z                                                           
    20: ifeq          34
    23: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;                                              
    26: ldc           #6                  // String empty                                                                                  
    28: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V                                      
    31: goto          42
    34: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;                                              
    37: ldc           #7                  // String othereise                                                                              
    39: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V                                      
    42: return
```

Now when you run the TestNPE driver with the agent, you'll get this

```
$ java -agentpath:libRichNPE.o TestNPE
about to throw NPE
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: location=17
    at TestNPE.main(TestNPE.java:7)
```

So that points to the invokevirtual #5 at offset 17! Just **HOW COOL IS THAT?**

Comment: Good question, but also keep in mind that if the line is dense the code quality is probably less than optimal.

Comment: I know you can't get the column number...but if you can use returns to break the calls on that line out to a series of lines `Java` will print the relevant row number while still treating it as a line.

Comment: It depends on the JVM implementation. For instance SAP JVM prints the field name which was null in the exception message.

Comment: Edit to add newlines.

Comment: @Svetlin Zarev: There is also a JEP https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8220715 that contributes the functionality of SAPJVM to OpenJDK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When an exception happens, JVM knows the original bytecode that caused the exception. However, `StackTraceElement` does not track bytecode indices.

The solution is to capture bytecode index using [JVMTI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html) whenever exception occurs.

The following sample JVMTI agent will intercept all exceptions, and if exception type is `NullPointerException`, the agent will replace its `detailMessage` with the bytecode location information.

```
#include <jvmti.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static jclass NullPointerException;
static jfieldID detailMessage;

void JNICALL VMInit(jvmtiEnv* jvmti, JNIEnv* env, jthread thread) {
    jclass localNPE = env->FindClass("java/lang/NullPointerException");
    NullPointerException = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef(localNPE);

    jclass Throwable = env->FindClass("java/lang/Throwable");
    detailMessage = env->GetFieldID(Throwable, "detailMessage", "Ljava/lang/String;");
}

void JNICALL ExceptionCallback(jvmtiEnv* jvmti, JNIEnv* env, jthread thread,
                               jmethodID method, jlocation location, jobject exception,
                               jmethodID catch_method, jlocation catch_location) {
    if (env->IsInstanceOf(exception, NullPointerException)) {
        char buf[32];
        sprintf(buf, "location=%ld", (long)location);
        env->SetObjectField(exception, detailMessage, env->NewStringUTF(buf));
    }
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, char* options, void* reserved) {
    jvmtiEnv* jvmti;
    vm->GetEnv((void**)&jvmti, JVMTI_VERSION_1_0);

    jvmtiCapabilities capabilities = {0};
    capabilities.can_generate_exception_events = 1;
    jvmti->AddCapabilities(&capabilities);

    jvmtiEventCallbacks callbacks = {0};
    callbacks.VMInit = VMInit;
    callbacks.Exception = ExceptionCallback;
    jvmti->SetEventCallbacks(&callbacks, sizeof(callbacks));
    jvmti->SetEventNotificationMode(JVMTI_ENABLE, JVMTI_EVENT_VM_INIT, NULL);
    jvmti->SetEventNotificationMode(JVMTI_ENABLE, JVMTI_EVENT_EXCEPTION, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile this into a shared library and run java with `-agentpath` option:

```
java -agentpath:/pato/to/libRichNPE.so Main
```

Comment: Oh, this is interesting! Thanks. I'll give that a try.

Comment: @apngin: Sorry, how do I compile this into a shared library?

Comment: I've got the following error while trying to compile it http://paste.ubuntu.com/23339517/

Comment: @OneTwoThree This is C++ source. Try `g++ -shared -fPIC -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/include -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/include/linux -o libRichNPE.so RichNPE.cpp`

Comment: Oh, yes! It compiled! But when I ran it, I'm not seeing anything different: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23339661/

Comment: @OneTwoThree Yes, there was a mistake in the code. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. Thank you. This has got to be the coolest trick I've learnt. :)

Comment: PS: Just edited the question to include your solution and output of the run. It's just too cool :)

Comment: Could you please add an example detail message to the answer? I would be intrested in how it actually looks.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker There is an example in the question: `java.lang.NullPointerException: location=17`

Answer (score 1):

The exception itself does not have enough information to provide more than line numbers.

One option i see is to use a bytecode debugger like bytecode visualizer to closer localize the bytecode instruction that causes the npe. Step forward until the exception occurs, or add a breakpoint for npe.

Answer (score 1):

[JEP 358: Helpful NullPointerExceptions](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8220715) adds such a feature to OpenJDK 14. It is disabled by default; you have to specify `-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages` to enable it. With it, your example results in:

```
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.isEmpty()" because "st" is null
    at TestNPE.main(TestNPE.java:7)
```

Classes do not need to be recompiled to take advantage of this feature. It was originally developed for the [SAP JVM](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ASJAVA/SAP+JVM).

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace mechanism relies on the debugging metadata optionally compiled into each class (namely the SourceFile and LineNumberTable attributes). As far as I know, bytecode offsets are not preserved anywhere. However, these would not be useful for a typical Java program, since you still have know what code each bytecode instruction corresponds to.

However, there is an obvious workaround - just break the code in question up into multiple lines and recompile! You can insert whitespace almost anywhere in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can either break up the complex line into many smaller ones you can trace, or you use your debugger to see what value was `null` when the exception occurred.

While you could try to look at the byte code where this happened, this will only be the start of a complex journey.  I suggest making your code simpler to understand and you might work out which values could be `null` (Note: it could be `null` unless you know it's not possible)