# Get the operation attempted in case of NPE

Tags: java, jvm

Consider the below code:

```
String s = null;
s.toLowerCase();
```

It throws a NPE:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at pracJava1.Prac.main(Prac.java:7)

The question is: Why can't the JVM also put a helper message saying:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException. Attempted `toLowerCase() on null`

This is useful in cases like `obj.setName(s.toLowerCase())`, where the line number is not sufficient to guess if `obj` was null or `s`.

---

On the feasibility of it, lets look at the byte code generated:

```
      stack=1, locals=2, args_size=1
     0: aconst_null
     1: astore_1
     2: aload_1
     3: invokevirtual #2    // Method java/lang/String.toLowerCase:()Ljava/lang/String;
```

So may be it does know, the method name it attempted the operation on. JVM experts, what's your opinion?

Comment: A NPE with as argument the method name could have been trhown by invoke_virtual. Would have saved me searching on the line for which object is null. On the other hand many work is done on the JMV and this is a minor improvement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why can't the JVM also put a helper message

First of all, JVM **can** do this. For example, SAP JVM indeed [provides extended messages](https://youtu.be/IsERHnGn7Vs?t=2109) for NullPointerExceptions, ClassCastExceptions etc.

There were [requests](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4834738) to do the same for HotSpot JVM, but they were closed as Will-Not-Fix for the reasons mentioned in @StephenC answer.

However, it is possible to enrich NullPointerException messages with the help of [JVM TI agent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html).

[**The example of extending NPE messages**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40060451/3448419)

Answer (score 5):

One possible reason for not doing this is it can break old Java code.  In all implementations of classic Java since the beginning, the message attribute of an NPE thrown by the JVM itself has been `null`.

Any changes that break old application code are damaging to the Sun / Oracle business model for Java.  All the evidence suggests that Sun / Oracle try to avoid this unless the alternative is **worse**.

(Occasionally mistakes / misjudgments are made and an (arguably) unnecessary "breaking" change to Java slips through.  We see the resulting "howls of outrage" from certain quarters, and I imagine that Oracle also gets feedback via their customer contacts.)

Android "Java" does this differently.  (And this shows that NPE error messages would be *technically* feasible in Java)  But Google did not need to worry about compatibility for old classic Java applications.  They dispensed with that problem when the replaced swathes of the standard Java SE libraries with Android alternatives.

---

You commented:

> But Oracle did break compatibility changes many a times, where the api specification was not broken (but the internals were of-course changed). If someone was parsing the NPE error message, I don't think that is a good enough reason :)

These are good debating points (maybe).

However, this decision is not open for debate.  It was a **business** decision that Sun made many years ago and Oracle has chosen to uphold.  We don't know what the real reasoning. and what you or I think about the *hypothesized* reasoning has no bearing.

For the record, this was proposed as an RFE ([JDK-4834738](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4834738)) back in 2003.  The issue was ultimately closed in 2014 as WNF (will not fix).  No reason was given (publicly).

Comment: But Oracle did break compatibility changes many a times, where the api specification was not broken (but the internals were of-course changed). 

If someone was parsing the NPE error message, I dont think that is a good enough reason :)

Comment: Yup. It seems based on this tweet (https://twitter.com/shipilev/status/880028188113608708), SAP JVM also does it.

Comment: Any code relying on a `null` message in JVM generated `NullPointerException` instances has serious problems surely making it break after the smallest environmental changes anyway. I can’t even imagine *how* application code could rely on this. Also, a lot of library code which formerly bailed out with a JVM generated NPE does a pre-test nowadays using `if` or `Objects.requireNonNull` and will produce an NPE with a message string instead of `null`.

Comment: All valid points.  However, this doesn't have much bearing on the **business* reasons for not making a "breaking" change.  (The enterprise IT manager at Acme Corp who signs off on their expensive yearly Java support contract *does not want to hear* that some employee of the company 20 years ago wrote some code with "problems" in it.  He only cares that Oracle has caused him to spend money checking and/or fixing old apps.  He would not be a happy person.   Unhappy managers are less inclined to renew support contracts.)

Comment: Just a thought, can someone with a OpenJDK bug system account ask the reasoning behind this to Oracle again, now? Thanks!

Comment: 1) I don't think so.  There is no evidence that non-Oracle people are able to comment on resolved tickets.  2) There is about zero chance (IMO) that anyone at Oracle would respond.  Like I said, it is a **business** decision.

Comment: Well, then, there is no prove that this has been a business decision, as apparently, only the one guy who closed the RFE with “won’t fix” knows the exact reason why he did so and whether or not other people were involved in that decision. It’s even possible that this guy can’t remember.

Comment: It is a business decision almost by definition.  Whether it was for the reasons I posited, or some other reason (e.g. too much effort, too little time, not enough skilled developers on the payroll, doesn't contribute to bottom line, etc) is speculation.  Bear in mind that the RFE remained open for a long time with no visible comments on it ... and 3 dups.  The lack of any public discussion of technical merit is (IMO) telling ... that the WNF was not for technical reasons.